# Where do hackers usually run their hacking script?

Tags: hacked

So in my quest to solve [this mystery](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60585/websites-defaced-by-uploading-script-using-theme-editor), I actually found some script that might be similar to one used to deface our sites: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hcvPE8YV

Now my question is where do they usually run this? Do they run it inside the hacked server or their own PCs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They run it on your server, just like any other script runs (including WordPress).

In the log you provided, it looks like the hacker knew your password. Perhaps you are using the same password on other sites, and he somehow gained access to one of them?

Always set different and complex passwords; combine a large character range; include special characters and so on...

Comment: I really like to believe he knows the password but these are not my personal sites, these are shared hosting clients' sites. All passwords are different. The logs show they hit wp-login right away like it's being run from a script. It is also worth noting that the root account was never used since I am always notified if there was a root login.

The hacker appears to change the password first in the DB before he logs to WP directly through automated scripts not manually. How they edit the database password without root access is a mystery to me. Access logs don't show any trace of their IP.

Comment: The only trace of their IP is only in the logs I provided, nothing more.

Comment: Hacker appears to be a member of indonesiandefacer.org as I saw it as one of the referrers in the logs.

Comment: then you provided partial logs; I don't see anything there that might suggest he changed your password trough another script

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, there are no more relevant data aside from that.

Comment: Wait, I actually found something interesting. I edited my original post http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60585/websites-defaced-by-uploading-script-using-theme-editor 

Do you have an idea where their tool might reside in the server?

Comment: That's not very helpful :) He might have found your FTP password. Check your FTP log. Is this your own server btw? Because hosting companies usually have some kind of protection at this level, like limiting the number of FTP login attempts to avoid successful brute-force attacks...